# Visual Studio 2013 VC++ float -1.#IDN000

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have this problem probably some specific VC++ problem. 
If I try call m_sqrt(4,2) then it returns 2.0000 and save it to float var. everything OK but for any differnt value returned by m_sqrt it ends with -1.#IND0000 Any idea why?

I was trying a diffrent optimalizations for compiler but nothing. 

Visual Studio 2013 Pro. (Default setting for VC++ Console Project)

Debuger screens:
http://2imgs.com/2i/i/5293e163/767cd5f994efbb8e4123b40a8cb14d14/7acd1c36e5.f.png

Comment: You should do your best to post all important information *here*, as text, *where possible*. Please read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to better understand how to write great questions.

Comment: You are taking the square root of a negative number.  The result is "negative indefinite NaN" or -1#IND in CRT speak.  Fix your bug.